# Adopting "Growing Object-Oriented Software" techniques to Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, interface, rspec, mocking

I read [Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/Growing-ObjectOriented-Software-Guided-by-Tests/9780321503626.page) by Steve Freeman and Nat Pryce and was impressed very much. I want to adopt the ideas of this book in my Rails projects using RSpec, though its examples are written in Java.

A basic precept of this book is that we should mock *interfaces* instead of *concrete classes*. They say we can improve the application *design* by extracting interfaces and naming them.

But, Ruby doesn't have any syntax equivalent to Java's `interface`. How can I utilize their techniques for Rails projects?

**UPDATE**

For example, in the page 126 the authors introduced `Auction` interface in order to implement the `bid` method. Firstly, they mocked `Auction.class` to make the test pass, then they implemented an `Auction` class as anonymous inner class in the `Main` class. Finally, they extracted a new concrete class `XMPPAuction` from `Main` (page 131-132).

This incremental approach is the crux of this book in my opinion.

How can I adopt or imitate such a series of code transformation in the Ruby development?

Comment: I replaced the word "concept" with "syntax" after reading the answers of Prakash and Andy. And removed the word "Unfortunately" to avoid an impression that I miss Java's `interface`. I love Ruby's *duck typing*. What I want is not an enforcement method in Java's manner. See the text after **UPDATE** for my intention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this previous [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4439733/429758) for a good explanation of interfaces in ruby.

Also, [Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby](http://www.poodr.info/book/) is a book in similar vein as [Growing Object Oriented Software](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/Growing-ObjectOriented-Software-Guided-by-Tests/9780321503626.page) book, but with ruby examples. Worth checking it out.

Answer (score 3):

Since in Ruby, all things are duck-typed and the interface is simply the set of fields and methods that are publicly exposed you can do one or more of the following:

**Test**

Design your tests to test interfaces and name and comment *your tests* appropriately - then you can pass all of your "concrete implementations" of your "interface" through the same test suite.  As long as your test suite covers your application's edge cases anything in your application that takes an instance of any of these concrete classes will be able to handle an instance of any of the *other* concrete classes.

**Use base classes**

Define a base class that all of your concrete classes will inherit from where all of the methods throw a `NotImplemented` error.  This gives you a hierarchy that you can visualize - however, it does require extra classes and may encourage numerous `is a` tests in your production code rather than that code relying on `has a`.

Comment: You're right. I'd be a bit careful of using base classes to define interface. Partly because you might need class inheritance to share some implementation, and partly because you might want to implement multiple interfaces in a class.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that Ruby does not have formal interfaces. Instead, interfaces are implicit in the messages that an object handles (see [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)).

If you are still looking for a more formal way to "enforce" an interface in Ruby, consider writing a suite of automated unit tests that are green if an object conforms to the interface properly, and are red otherwise.

For examples, see [ActiveModel::Lint::Tests](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Lint/Tests.html) and [rspec's shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).