# Ruby YARD: documenting abstract methods implementations

Tags: ruby, abstract, documentation-generation, yard

I have a typical OO pattern: one base abstract class (that defines abstract methods) and several classes that implement these abstract methods in class-specific way.

I'm used to write documentation only once in abstract methods and then it automatically propagates to several concrete classes (at least it works the following way in Javadoc, in Scaladoc, in Doxygen), i.e. I don't need to repeat the same description in all concrete classes.

However, I couldn't find how to do such propagation in YARD. I've tried, for example:

```
# Some description of abstract class.
# @abstract
class AbstractClass
  # Some method description.
  # @return [Symbol] some return description
  # @abstract
  def do_something
    raise AbstractMethodException.new
  end
end

class ConcreteClass < AbstractClass
  def do_something
    puts "Real implementation here"
    return :foo
  end
end
```

What I get:

- Code works as expected - i.e. throws `AbstractMethodException` is called in abstract class, does the job in concrete class
- In YARD, `AbstractClass` is clearly defined as abstract, `ConcreteClass` is normal
- Method description and return type is good in `AbstractClass`
- Method is said to throw `AbstractMethodException` in `AbstractClass`
- Method has no description at all and generic `Object` return type in `ConcreteClass`, there's not a single notice of that an abstract method exists in base class.

What I expect to get:

- Method's description and return type are inherited (i.e. copied) to `ConcreteClass` from info at `AbstractClass`
- Ideally, this method is specified in "inherited" or "implemented" section of `ConcreteClass` description, with some reference link from `ConcreteClass#do_something` to `AbstractMethod#do_something`.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue boils down to what you're trying to do. It looks like you're trying to implement an Interface in Ruby, which makes sense if you're coming from Java or .NET, but isn't really how Ruby developers tend to work.

Here is some info about how the typical thought on Interfaces in Ruby: [What is java interface equivalent in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437291/what-is-java-interface-equivalent-in-ruby)

That said, I understand what you're trying to do. If you don't want your AbstractClass to be implemented directly, but you want to define methods that can be used in a class that behaves like the AbstractClass stipulates (as in [Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)), then you probably want to use a Module. Modules work very well for keeping your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), but they don't quite solve your problem related to documenting [overridden methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding). So, at this point I think you can reconsider how you approach documentation, or at least approach it in a more Ruby-ish way.

Inheritance in Ruby is really (generally speaking from my own experience) only used for a few reasons:

- Reusable code and attributes
- Default behaviors
- Specialization

There are obviously other edge cases, but honestly this is what inheritance tends to be used for in Ruby. That doesn't mean what you're doing won't work or violates some rule, it just isn't typical in Ruby (or most dynamically typed languages). This atypical behavior is probably why YARD (and other Ruby doc generators) doesn't do what you expect. That said, creating an abstract class that only defines the methods that must exist in a subclass really gains you very little from a code perspective. Methods not defined will result in a NoMethodError exception being thrown anyway, and you could programmatically check if an object will respond to a method call (or any message for that matter) from whatever calls the method, using `#respond_to?(:some_method)` (or other reflective tools for getting meta stuff). It all comes back Ruby's use of [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

For pure documentation, why document a method that you don't actually use? You shouldn't really care about the *class* of the object being sent or received from calling a method, just what those objects *respond to*. So don't bother creating your AbstractClass in the first place if it adds no real value here. If it contains methods you actually will call directly without overriding, then create a Module, document them there, and run `$ yardoc --embed-mixins` to include methods (and their descriptions) defined in mixed-in Modules. Otherwise, document methods where you actually implement them, as each implementation *should* be different (otherwise why re-implement it).

Here is how I would something similar to what you're doing:

```
# An awesome Module chock-full of reusable code
module Stuff
  # A powerful method for doing things with stuff, mostly turning stuff into a Symbol
  def do_stuff(thing)
    if thing.kind_of?(String)
      return thing.to_sym
    else
      return thing.to_s.to_sym
    end
  end
end

# Some description of the class
class ConcreteClass
  include Stuff

  # real (and only implementation)
  def do_something
    puts "Real implementation here"
    return :foo
  end
end

an_instance = ConcreteClass.new
an_instance.do_somthing       # => :foo
# > Real implementation here
an_instance.do_stuff("bar")   # => :bar
```

Running YARD (with --embed-mixins) will include the methods mixed-in from the Stuff module (along with their descriptions) and you now know that any object including the Stuff module will have the method you expect.

You may also want to look at [Ruby Contracts](https://github.com/egonSchiele/contracts.ruby), as it may be closer to what you're looking for to absolutely force methods to accept and return only the types of objects you want, but I'm not sure how that will play with YARD.

Comment: What if I want to provide documentation for other developers so that they can easily know what their classes (which in other languages would follow an interface) have to implement?

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but you can still use the `(see ParentClass#method)` construct (documented [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#Reference_Tags)). Not ideal because you have to type this manually for every overriding method.

That being said, I'm no Yard specialist but given its especially customizable architecture, I'd be surprised that there would be no easy way to implement what you need just by extending Yard, somewhere in the [Templates](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Templates.md) department I guess.